# How to use ilike percent signs with a session variable

Tags: postgresql

How to do something like this, in order to match the text anywhere in the column?

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn ilike %current_setting('myapp.var')%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE mycolumn ilike '%' || 
      (select current_setting('myapp.var')) || 
      '%';
```